# SSHing into several hosts sequentially from my local machine with one command

Tags: ssh, terminal, zsh

I am currently trying to write an alias which involves SSHing from my local machine into one host where I then SSH into one last machine. My bash skills aren't quite up to par and I can't seem to figure out whats going on.

Here's what I have

```
ssh -A my_user@host_1 -t "get_ip | sed -n 2p | xargs -I {} ssh -T my_user@{}"
```

Ultimately what I would like to do is run a single command from my local machine that:

1. SSHes me into the initial remote machine. Here I want to run get_ip and parse the output from that, which gives me an IP
2. The IP from step one is the final server I want to SSH into and get an active session running (do not want to just exit). This is what I am trying to do in the last part of my command.

In other words:

Run command on local machine -> Run command on first remote server and use output from that command to get ip for next machine -> SSH into last machine using IP I retrieved -> Have an open session last machine SSHed into

Right now my current command is returning:

```
Connection to host_1 closed
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for "with one command"? The *best* way to do this -- which will let you do, f/e, arbitrary port forwarding to the last-hop machine without forwarding those ports to the first-hop machine first -- requires using SSH multiplexing to reuse the same connection over multiple subsequent commands.

Comment: Want to improve my workflow by writing an alias.

Comment: Shell functions (which can include as many commands as they need to) are pretty much always preferable to aliases. Indeed, the freenode #bash factoid for "alias" is "if you have to ask, use a function instead".

Comment: If you won't accept a bash answer, remove the bash tag. zsh is not compatible with bash, it is not a superset of bash, and it's not appropriate to tag zsh questions with the "bash" tag.

Comment: Gotcha apologies for the confusion. Will remove bash.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a pipeline replaces stdin (so that input is coming from the now-empty pipe, not from your original terminal). Use a command substitution instead of `xargs`, and use `-tt` to force a TTY to be allocated at each stage:

```
ssh -ttA my_user@host_1 'ssh -tt "my_user@$(get_ip | sed -n 2p)"'
```

Even better:

```
sshWithCache() {
  ssh \
    -o "ControlPath $HOME/.ssh/control:%h:%p:%r" \
    -o "ControlMaster auto" \
    -o "ControlPersist 5m" \
    "$@"
}

sshIndirectly() {
  local ip
  ip=$(sshWithCache my_user@host_1 'get_ip | sed -n 2p')
  sshWithCache -o "ProxyJump my_user@host_1" "my_user@$ip" "$@"
}
```

...after which you can run `sshIndirectly someCommand` to invoke `someCommand` on host_2. Because of the `ControlPath`/`ControlMaster` configuration, only one actual SSH connection to host_1 is created, and authentication is only performed a single time.

Comment: Getting `zsh: no matches found: ssh -tt "my_user@$(get_ip | sed -n 2p)"`

Comment: Code is tested for bash -- which is the shell your question is tagged for -- not zsh. zsh is deliberately noncompliant with the POSIX sh standard, and I don't support/endorse/condone/assist others with its use.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the longer (two-function) form work with zsh, or do you have the same problem there? And if it fails, do you get an error message that narrows down the issue more clearly?

Comment: When I try the two function approach it hangs.

Comment: What's the last line written by `set -x; sshIndirectly`?